# Is Oracle's SYSTIMESTAMP constant inside a single transaction?

Tags: oracle

Or is it actually evaluated every time?

[Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm) does not specify. (Or is perhaps the fact that is a *function* considered to say it gets executed every time?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`SYSTIMESTAMP` gets evaluated for every statement**, as the following snippet demonstrates.

However, Oracle's [documentation on Statement-Level Read Consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#i17841) seems to say that **when I use `systimestamp` multiple times in a single statement, it will always result in the same value** .

Comment in either `--AAA--` or `--BBB--`:

```
create table timestamptest (ts timestamp);

delete timestamptest;
declare now timestamp;
begin
  select systimestamp into now from dual;
  FOR i in 1..10000 LOOP
--AAA--   insert into timestamptest values (systimestamp);
--BBB--   insert into timestamptest values (now);
  END LOOP;
end;
/
select count(distinct ts) from timestamptest;
```

---

**Result for --AAA--**:

```
> select count(distinct ts) from timestamptest;
-------------------+
 COUNT(DISTINCTTS) |
-------------------+
                30 |
-------------------+
```

**Result for --BBB--**:

```
> select count(distinct ts) from timestamptest;
-------------------+
 COUNT(DISTINCTTS) |
-------------------+
                 1 |
-------------------+
```

Comment: +1 It might also be worth noting that SYSTIMESTAMP and SYSDATE are not even necessarily constant within a single *statement*, depending on the context.  See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7954509/409172) for details.