# When is systimestamp generated by Oracle

Tags: oracle

When is the return value of `systimestamp` function generated in an Oracle sql query? Returned value concerns the moment in which the query is submitted or is ended? And if the function is used in a subquery?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE**: The discussion below is for SQL **only**. The behavior of `sysdate` and `systimestamp` is different in PL/SQL, the procedural programming language associated with Oracle SQL. Please see Jon Heller's comment below this Answer, and the link he provides in the comment. **END OF NOTE**

`systimestamp` is calculated once, at the BEGINNING of the execution of a query. It will have the same value within the query and all its subqueries, no matter how deep and no matter how many times `systimestamp` is referenced in the query.

For example, the following (intentionally convoluted) query will always return zero:

```
select sum (abs(   date '2000-01-01' 
                 + ( systimestamp - (select systimestamp from dual) )
                 - date '2000-01-01'
               )
           )
from   dual
connect by level <= 300000;
```

**NOTE**: In a comment below this Answer, the OP points out that - while `systimestamp - systimestamp` always returns zero, as it should, `systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1)` returns something like `+01 00:00:00.762611`. Which is unexpected. So let's explain that.

Date arithmetic with numbers (like 1 to represent one day) is for expressions of `date` data type - not for timestamps. So for the operation `systimestamp - 1`, the timestamp is *truncated* first - only whole seconds are kept, and the fraction of second after the decimal point is discarded.

Then, for an operation of type [timestamp] - [date], Oracle will first cast the date as a timestamp, and then take the difference and return an interval. Which is what the OP saw. The fraction of a second is due to truncation for the `systimestamp - 1` calculation, while the first `systimestamp` is not truncated.

To get the same calculation "done right" (and to see that indeed the result will be exactly `+01 00:00:00.000000`), we must use the proper data type when we subtract one day from `systimestamp`. Namely, just like numbers are "what we should use" for date arithmetic, for **timestamp** arithmetic we must use the `interval` data type.

```
select systimestamp - (systimestamp - interval '1' day) from dual
```

will always return exactly `+01 00:00:00.000000`.

Comment: I tried this query: select systimestamp - systimestamp from dual; and it returns 0. This one instead select systimestamp - (systimestamp-1) from dual; returns +01 00:00:00.762611. Following your answer difference should be 1 day (without milliseconds) ...

Comment: @FrancescoSerra - That is because subtracting 1 (to mean one day) is a `date` operation. The timestamp is cast as date (meaning, the fraction of a second in the timestamp is *truncated* away.) Instead of subtracting 1, subtract `interval '1' day` - subtracting interval from timestamp returns timestamp and there is no rounding or truncation involved. You will see that the result is exactly 1 day.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the same is *not* true for PL/SQL code, which will re-evaluate a systimestamp every time it's called, as I demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7963249/409172).

Comment: @JonHeller - Good point, I will add something to my answer to alert readers to that. It makes sense for PL/SQL to behave differently; it is a *procedural* language, there is no concept of "read consistency" in procedural languages. In your other post, one may get the wrong impression that the difference is between "procedure" and "function", since a function can be called from SQL but a procedure can't. Actually, a function can be called from PL/SQL code, and in that case there will be no "read consistency" either.

Comment: @mathguy Good point, I updated my answer to try to make it clearer.  Thanks.